# Pallet Call Indicies are Conflicting Error

Tags: pallet, substrateinterface, pallet-staking

This error cropped up somewhat unexpectedly, and I am not sure how it came to be. Nevertheless, it appears that 2 runtime calls, `set_commission` (a new function being added in the PR in question) and `set_configs` have an index clash error, within the `nomination-pools` pallet:

```
Call indices are conflicting: Both functions set_commission and set_configs are at index 11
    --> frame/nomination-pools/src/lib.rs:2237:10
     |
2237 |         pub fn set_commission(
     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: Call indices are conflicting: Both functions set_commission and set_configs are at index 11
    --> frame/nomination-pools/src/lib.rs:2329:10
     |
2329 |         pub fn set_configs(
     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- `cargo clean` does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A macro was introduced to pallets to explicitly define an index for each runtime call.

If the pallet you are working on uses this macro, ensure that newly added calls also have a call index. E.g.:

```
#[pallet::call_index(11)]
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::set_configs())]
pub fn set_configs(
...
```